# Spring @Autowired on a class new instance

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm not so familiar with Spring and I have the following situation:

A repository class:

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {
    // ...
}
```

A class that uses the repository class:

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractClass {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    //...
}
```

I know that if I annotate my `MyClass` with `@Component` and use it with an `@Autowired`, then the `@Autowired` `MyRepository` is resolved just fine.
Problem is I am in a situation that I need to create new instances of `MyClass` with reflection. So `MyRepository` is never resolved and is null all the time.

**Is there a way to use `@Autowired` in this situation?**

Explaining better my situation:
I have some implementations of `AbstractClass`.
In a setup phase of my application I create a `HashMap` of these implementations. Basically:

```
{"MyClass", MyClass.class}
//...
```

Then I have a generic `Controller` that maps to the url `/{class}?options=...`
Using the `{class}` `@PathVariable`, the `HashMap` above and reflection I am able to create a instance of a class based on the given `options` (this part is important). Do you guys think there's a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you create new instances of `MyClass` with reflection? Can you post the code for that?

Comment: Hi Maruthi, It's a simple `map.get(className).newInstance()`

Comment: @JoãoMenighin looked at my answer? does it work for you?

Comment: Spring does not work this way. `@Autowired` is a constructor created by Spring. You can't create a new instance of a class on your own and expect Spring to inject its `@Autowired` classes

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Spring itself offers some functionality for doing auto-wiring in your objects
which you created by `new` or `newInstance()` or whatever.

To use it you need an [`AutowireCapableBeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html)
which you get by Spring's normal dependency injection with `@Autowired`.

```
@Autowired
private  AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory;
```

Then you use its [`autowireBean(Object)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#autowireBean-java.lang.Object-) method
to inject the `@Autowired` properties into your bean.

```
Object myBean = map.get(className).newInstance();
autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(myBean);
```

---

Design note:

Think well if you really need the approach above.
The javadoc of [`AutowireCapableBeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html) advises against using this interface for most use-cases:

> This subinterface of BeanFactory is not meant to be used in normal application code: stick to `BeanFactory` or `ListableBeanFactory` for typical use cases.
>
> Integration code for other frameworks can leverage this interface to wire and populate existing bean instances that Spring does not control the lifecycle of. This is particularly useful for WebWork Actions and Tapestry Page objects, for example.

Comment: I am not going to downvote you, but consider you have a downvote  from me. I will just quote you one sentence from javadoc. "This subinterface of BeanFactory is not meant to be used in normal application code: stick to BeanFactory or ListableBeanFactory for typical use cases.

Integration code for other frameworks can leverage this interface to wire and populate existing bean instances that Spring does not control the lifecycle of. This is particularly useful for WebWork Actions and Tapestry Page objects, for example"

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov I agree. This approach is kind of smelly
and should be avoided if there are cleaner solutions possible.

Comment: This is actually my case I think. I'm kinda building up a mini framework to generate  code... It's really good to know about this. Another approach that worked for me was making my `MyClass` marked with `Scope("prototype")` (so it would get a new instance everytime) and using the `ApplicationContext.getBean()` method.
Since my question was basically "Is there a way to Autowire an object outside Spring lifecycle?", I think your answer fits best. I will give an upvote to the others. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @ThomasFritsch maybe you could edit your answer with Alexandar's comment so people getting here would know about this "caveat" on the java doc. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoãoMenighin good point, I've added Alexandar's objection into my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Factory Design Pattern](https://www.journaldev.com/1392/factory-design-pattern-in-java) over here.

This might seem a little complicated in start but I am sure you will love it after you have implemented it.

Steps:

1. Add @Component on all implementations of AbstractClass.
2. Create a factory class as:

   ```
   @Component
   public class MyFactory {

       private final Map<String, AbstractClass> impletationMap = new HashMap<>();

       @Autowired
       ApplicationContext context;

       @PostConstruct
       public void initialize() {
           populateDataMapperMap(context.getBeansOfType(AbstractClass.class).values().iterator());
       }

       private void populateDataMapperMap(final Iterator<AbstractClass> classIterator) {
           while (classIterator.hasNext()) {
               AbstractClass abstractClassImpl = (AbstractClass) classIterator.next();
               impletationMap.put(abstractClassImpl.getClass().getName(), abstractClassImpl);

           }
       }
   }
   ```

When the Bean of this MyFactory class is initialized, then it will lookup for all beans of type AbstractClass and put them in the HashMap(implementationMap).

Now from this factory you can get the HashMap and then get the implementations as and when you require. It will be very easy when you add new implementation of AbstractClass as factory will take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

One work around is instead of binding the MyClass to the Hashmap to bind a Factory class. MyClassFactory. This way you will delegate the construction to a concrete factory that will do the job to instantiate the correct class and initialize the correct repository.

Here is an example:

```
{"MyClass", MyClassFactory.class}
```

The factory can be Component as well, then you need to bind the hashmap to the factory instance instead of the factory class. But lets say it is not a component:

```
//@Component   this is optional
    public MyClassFactory {
        //@Autowired optional
        ApplicationContext ctx;


       public MyClass createInstance() {
            MyRepository repo = ctx.getBean("")
            MyClass myclass = new MyClass(repo)
            return myclass;
       }
    }
```

If you mark it as component you can well also use ApplicationContextAware interface if you are going to autowire the ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to declare `@Component` on top of `MyClass`.

Then, in the setup phase, you can pass the *instance* of `MyClass` instead of `MyClass.class` itself, in the HashMap. There won't be any need to create instances via reflection.

**Note:** You can fetch the instance of `MyClass` from your `ApplicationContext` in the setup phase.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pankaj, the problem is that I can't have singletons of this guy. Each instance may depend on the `options` given in the URL... Any ideas? hmm

Comment: you can then pass an instance of a factory class, that can fetch you beans at runtime based on the options that you can pass give via it's constructor. But, the instance has to be generated via spring, else it won't work.

Comment: @JoãoMenighin Refer this example for implementing factory design pattern - https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-create-beans-using-static-factory-method/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Component    
public class SomeClass extends AbstractClass {

  private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  public MyClass getMyClass(){
      // Now @Autowired MyRepository will work
      return applicationContext.getBean(MyClass.class);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can annotate all your AbstractClass implementation beans with @Component and use the next declaration

```
@Autowired
private List<AbstractClass> beans;
```

You can then convert that to a Map in a @PostConstruct method.

Spring won't complain about duplicate definitions if you autowire Lists.