# @Autowired repository in service class with use of Factory Design Pattern

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to autowire repository in class which is initialized by factory pattern.

Let me explain step by step.

My repository class:

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository {
    //
}
```

Other class that uses the repository class and extend some Abstract class:

```
public class OtherClass extends AbstractClass {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    //
}
```

Now I have created on Factory class which Initialized this OtherClass and put in one map.

```
@Component
public class TempFactory {
    private final Map<Class, AbstractTest> impletationMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        populateDataMapperMap(context.getBeansOfType(AbstractTest.class).values().iterator());
    }

    private void populateDataMapperMap(final Iterator<AbstractClass> classIterator) {
        while (classIterator.hasNext()) {
            AbstractTest abstractClassImpl = (AbstractClass) classIterator.next();
            impletationMap.put(abstractClassImpl.getClass(), abstractClassImpl);

        }
    }

}
```

Now the problem here is that object which put in impletationMap is not autowire the userRepository and return null.

```
    Output:

    Otherclass oc = (AbstractClass)impletationMap.get("key")

    userRepository is null in oc object.
```

I come to this solution by [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355132/spring-autowired-on-a-class-new-instance)

Please tell me how to proceed further.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should annotate OtherClass with @Component.
And i had a try.here is my code,hope this could help you.

```
public class AbstractClass {
}
```

```
@Component
public class OtherClass extends AbstractClass {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserRepository getUserRepository() {
        return userRepository;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class TempFactory {
    private final Map<Class, AbstractClass> impletationMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    public Map<Class, AbstractClass> getImpletationMap() {
        return impletationMap;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        populateDataMapperMap(context.getBeansOfType(AbstractClass.class).values().iterator());
    }

    private void populateDataMapperMap(final Iterator<AbstractClass> classIterator) {
        while (classIterator.hasNext()) {
            AbstractClass abstractClassImpl = classIterator.next();
            impletationMap.put(abstractClassImpl.getClass(), abstractClassImpl);
        }
    }

}
```

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository {
}
```

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml")
public class ATest {
    @Autowired
    TempFactory tempFactory;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        OtherClass otherClass = (OtherClass) tempFactory.getImpletationMap().get(OtherClass.class);
        UserRepository userRepository = otherClass.getUserRepository();
        Assert.assertNotNull(userRepository);
    }

}
```