# @Autowired Spring Boot component is initialized in parent base class but happen to be null in child class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inheritance, junit

Why the `myComponent` ends up being null in child junit test class? How to fix it?

**Base JUnit test class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class BaseTest {
 @Autowired
 MyComponent myComponent;

 @Configuration
 @Import(MyComponentBaseConfiguration.class)
 static class Cfg {
  @Bean
  MyComponent myComponent() {
   return new MyComponent();
  }
 }
void convert(MyComponentInterface component) {
  // here component is null
}
 @Test
 public void test() {
  BaseTestChild child = new BaseTestChild();
  child.test();
 }
}
```

**Child test class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class BaseTestChild extends BaseTest {
@Test
    public void test() {
        convert(myComponent);  // here myComponent is null
    }
}
```

Comment: you're initializing a new instance of a class.

Comment: Thanks for hint. One option to solve it: `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52355649/480632.